# How to make a config file property unique with config parser?

Tags: python, parsing, config

How can I create a config file with unique only one unique property?
Or are there any loop for checking the config file where I find a duplicated name property value and it gives an exception?

```
[NAME+TIMESTAMP]
Name=UNIQUE NAME
Property=something
Property1=something1
Property2=something2

[NAME+TIMESTAMP]
Name=UNIQUE NAME
Property=something
Property1=something1
Property2=something2
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague. Do you mean that the row `Name=UNIQUE NAME` should be unique in the entire file, or do you only want `UNIQUE NAME` to unique inside of one config-block? Also, if it's unique in the entire file, should the other properties still be set?

Comment: Right now I working on a python script where with args.parser I give name and properties to a section. I would like to reach that Name=UNIQUE NAME is unique in the entire file and not just in the config-block. The other properties not so important like the name.

Comment: `configParser` objects are dict-like, so if that's what you're trying to accomplish, then you could just make the `key` for the block the `UNIQUE NAME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to `configParser` being dict-like in most things, what we can do here is use the `key` of the different code-blocks to make sure that there are unique blocks.

Here is a simple test to show it in action:

```
import configparser
class Container:
    configs=[] # keeps a list of all initialized objects.
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            self.__setattr__(k,v) # Sets each named attribute to their given value.
        Container.configs.append(self)

# Initializing some objects.
Container(
    Name="Test-Object1",
    Property1="Something",
    Property2="Something2",
    Property3="Something3",
 )
Container(
    Name="Test-Object2",
    Property1="Something",
    Property2="Something2",
    Property3="Something3",
 )
Container(
    Name="Test-Object2",
    Property1="Something Completely different",
    Property2="Something Completely different2",
    Property3="Something Completely different3",
 )
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
for item in Container.configs: # Loops through all the created objects.
    config[item.Name] = item.__dict__ # Adds all variables set on the object, using "Name" as the key.

with open("example.ini", "w") as ConfigFile:
    config.write(ConfigFile)
```

In the above example, I create three objects that contain variables to be set by configparser. However, the third object shares the `Name` variable with the second Object. That means that the third one will "overwrite" the second while writing the .ini file.

**example.ini**:

```
[Test-Object1]
name = Test-Object1
property1 = Something
property2 = Something2
property3 = Something3

[Test-Object2]
name = Test-Object2
property1 = Something Completely different
property2 = Something Completely different2
property3 = Something Completely different3
```

Comment: It is really helpful and useful, what about if I want to create the configfile's object with argparser in the terminal, I mean like this:  `python mypythonscript.py -f create -n  Test-Object1 -p1 something -p2 something2 -p3 something3 `

-f create mean the function that call the create method
-p1 p2 p3 is the property1,2,3
In this situation how can I check the file before create a new config-object?

Comment: I would then first parse the .ini file and see if the entry is already there. If it's not, then I would do some other logic to add it into the file. Keep in mind however, that `w` flag in the `open` function will overwrite the file, so you cannot just change one value, you will have to rewrite the whole file with that flag. If you get stuck with that however, consider opening a new question specifically for that new issue.